# iOS navigation controller storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I have this problem when I want to go from view controller to the details page using

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gotodetail" sender:nil];
```

but I face this problem
Could not find a navigation controller for segue '*gotodetail*'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of `UINavigationController`.'

but I add a navigation controller and the view controller and set it the root view controller

Comment: u were added the navigation controller in front of root view controller

Comment: if it is yes change [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gotodetail" sender:self];

Comment: yes, it is so  by what I should replace the self perform

Comment: can u add ur screens in screens shot

Comment: I can't because I don't have 10 reputations :(

Comment: can you please give me your Skype or email to send it to you?

Comment: Done I sent an email for you

Comment: no i can't I don't know why so please help me

Comment: i surely help u man, i saw ur screen shot, i can't understand man, can u come on chat karthik.saral@gmail.com

Comment: are you sure you clicked on the arrow[seque] and set it's name?

Comment: @Houssam now you can attach the screenshots :)